# Reading Style XAML from Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For Example I have resource file name theme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Color x:Key="TitleColor1">#e0e0e0</Color>
  <Color x:Key="TitleColor2">#616161</Color>
  <Color x:Key="TitleColor3">#404040</Color>
  <Color x:Key="TitleColor4">#bfbfbf</Color>
  <Color x:Key="TitleColor5">#7d0000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to read these element and set it in a Custom object.

```
public class ThemeModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string ColorString { get; set; }
}
```

What it the best way to do this?

Comment: What way did you implement? Maybe it is the best already. You did try something, right?

Comment: I was think of Regular expression to parse the text and insert them in to the object, but i was hoping for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you want your custom class when you can load the ResourceFile into ResourceDictionary object like

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Dictionary1.xaml", FileMode.Open);
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
```

Once your have dictionary object, you can use Keys and Values in whatever way you want.

Comment: XamlReader does not contain definition for load i guess

Comment: It does. Use System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Color c = (Color)FindResource("TitleColor1");
```

then you can cast/convert c to string or anything that you want to.

More about FindResource on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx)

Comment: I dont know the name of the keys given any xaml file with sets of color i would like to read it into an object

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to read TitleColor1 and put the value into 'Key' string object. What do you want to do? Can you elaborate please

Comment: I want parse the content of a Xaml file and create an list of ThemeModel

Answer (score 0):

You can access the resource dictionary elements by loading resource dictionary.After that you can access element using key from Resource Dictionary.

```
 var s = System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("URI for ResourceDictionary", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
        var color = s["TitleColor1"] as Color;
```